# RESTful API Error Handling

Tags: php, api, rest

I have a simple function that makes a cURL request to my RESTful API, and it returns data as it should when a successful request is made. My problem is, when a user perhaps gives the API wrong data or the API can't do what is requested, I don't know how to return error responses (e.g. 404s, 500s).

How would I go about doing this?

At the moment I have the following. In my API client

```
class Awesome_Api { 
    static function request($url, $data, $method)
    {
        // cURL stuffs here...

        if (successful)
        {
            return (success response)
        }
        else
        {
            return (error response)
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
$response = Awesome_Api::request($url, $data, $method);
```

Now how do I return an error response code from the API, and handle it in the client end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function to return error codes, like this:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
```

or

```
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not found');
```

It is very important that you make sure nothing has been written to the output before calling this function, otherwise it will not work as you expect.

In your client API, you can use the [`curl_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) and [`curl_errno()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) functions to retrieve information about the error number and message returned from the server.

Comment: Okay so I set the header in the API, but then how do I check/validate the response in the API client?

Comment: Thanks for that. I am still confused, however. What exactly do I need to return from my API, and what do I need to check for in my API client in terms of error responses?

Comment: That's up to you, since you don't provide any further information and you're the designer. If you're looking for inspiration, download your favorite client API and check how it handles the different error conditions that may get from the server, for example 404 or 500 errors.

Comment: Thanks mate. I figured it out. I am checking the response code using curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); and then returning exceptions to the client, which uses try{}catch(){} to handle any exceptions. Sound about right?

Comment: sounds great and IMHO that's the way to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your response guided me in the right direction, so I'll go with yours :)